# My HTML page appears not to be running my JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm really new to JavaScript and HTML so sorry for the basic question.  Basically I have this HTML file which is supposed to run my file script.js when it is loaded, my friend told me to use a $(function () { ) to contain the code so when I load the page it will run the whole script.  However nothing is happening when I run the script, the create webpage is supposed to set text in the div id = question_text after an array of objects is loaded into the the array questions.

Here is the head of my HTML as you can see I have added in script.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
  <title>Patient Questionnaire</title>

</html>
```

And here is my JavaScript

```
$(function() {

  questions = [];
  count = 0;
  addQuestions();
  createWebpage();

  function Question(questionText, possibleAnswers, chosenAnswer) {
    this.questionText = questionText;
    this.possibleAnswers = possibleAnswers;
    this.chosenAnswer = chosenAnswer;
  }

  function addQuestions() {
    var question1 = new Question(
      "Do you have or have you ever had high blood pressure?", ['Yes', 'No'],
      ""
    );

    var question2 = new Question(
      "Within the last year, have you had chest pain or pressure with activity such as walking or climbing stairs?", ['Yes', 'No'],
      ""
    );

    var question3 = new Question(
      "Do you currently take medication to prevent or reduce agnia (chest pain from the heart)?", ['Yes', 'No'],
      ""
    );

    var question4 = new Question(
      "Have you ever had a heart attack?" ['Yes', 'No'],
      ""
    );

    questions.push(question1);
    questions.push(question2);
    questions.push(question3);
    questions.push(question4);
  }

  function createWebpage() {
    document.getElementById("question_text").innerHTML = questions[1].questionText;
    console.log("questions")
  }

});
```

I've only used JavaScript a few times before but normally I have been able to get it working by getting the elementID and setting it to what I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you update with a file directory of your project?

Comment: You don't actually have jQuery.

Comment: Look at the error message in the console.

Comment: Console is already helping you, and you are not listening :-)

Comment: So I just need to download JQuery, had no idea what $ is not defined meant

Comment: your only jquery code  is the `$(function() { ... });` wrapper, which none of your code requires.  Remove this and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the following syntax in order to get your Javascript code executed:

```
(function(){ 
    ... 
})();
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/470sk1gd/

In my opinion there's no need to use jQuery in this case.

Comment: Thanks for this, my pal never told me he was using jQuery in a site he'd helped me with before

Answer (score 0):

1. Put `alert('Start');` in the first line of your JavaScript file to see if it gets loaded at all.
2. As SLaks said, for `$` to work, you need jQuery. So you need to load that too.